# x2goagent does not grab key combinations in windowed mode

Tags: remote-desktop, x2go, x2goclient

I use `x2go` (latest version installed from x2go ppa) to connect to another ubuntu 18.04 machine.

`x2go` has some shortcuts documented: https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:usage:x2goclient

I'm specifically interested in

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>: toggle autograb feature (pass all key to the x2go
> session when it is active; this helps with window cycling using
> Alt+Tab)

However, such shortcut seems to not work.
Indeed, when I set the Display to `Use whole display`, the keyboard shortcuts are "grabbed" (that is, I can change the active window by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
When I opt for `Fullscreen` or `Custom`, key combinations are not used by the x2go agent.

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> shortcut has no effect at all.

Is it possible to switch keyboard combinations from the client to the remote desktop session?

Comment: Found the same problem, sad to see that nobody provided a solution